# Iframe Popup close in iframe selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I have a page where a popup is created through iFrames.

I am working with Iframe - 1. After Click on iframe -1 , Iframe -2 popup happens.

I use switchTo().frame("iframe2") to switch to the popup.

I then successfully enter some text and look up a value
Once the value is found, I click on on it (still on the popup)

To close the popup I need to click on [x] image in div.

I used xpath ---> `{ "//*[@id='popCloseBox']"}` and 
I used cssSelector ---> `{#popCloseBox}`
and I used id ---> `By.id("popCloseBox"));`

But it is not clicking there and error show - no visible element.

I used switchTo().defaultcontent , but that is goes on to the Iframe-1 without closing Iframe -2 popup.It should go to the div#popup to click on [x] image in popup.

Ideas ? suggestions?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuWa8.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZbnG.png)

Comment: Is the popCloseBox in the same frame as the element you send the text to? Try to switch the driver direct to the popCloseBox: 

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("popCloseBox")));
WebElement Xbtn = driver.findElement(By.id("popCloseBox"));Xbtn.click();

Another option is to simulate pressing Esc: 

Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("popCloseBox"))); WebElement Xbtn = driver.findElement(By.id("popCloseBox"));Xbtn.click();  is not working.

Comment: The second method : Robot rob = new Robot(); rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE); rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) is not working as the iframe - 2 still not closed so I cannot able to identify any elements on iframe - 1.

Comment: Seems to me, javascript is blocked in the first frame. Can you try: 1. open the first frame by calling direct it's URL 2. run a simple js via greasmonkey or tampermonkey or something similar; 

var url = window.location.href;
window.prompt("url", url);